# Checkbox confirmation button missing from ngx mat date time picker

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-date-format

I had a styling issue with ngx mat datetime picker in Angular 15 which is this package..
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-components/datetime-picker

So I added
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons";
to my styles.scss and that fixed it.

However on occasion all the dates in the date picker were missing! I updated the package to a minor version and this fixed the issue but then noticed the checkbox to confirm your choice at the bottom the dialog went totally missing..

I am now in Angular 16 and the datetime picker is on version 16 as well.

Has anyone else had this problem? I am using a custom formatter that implements NgxDateAdaptor but I dont think its relevant, I took it out of providers and I still have the same problem. This is a weird rendering issue.

It looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From a certain version onwards, you have to add those buttons yourself:

```
<ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
    <ngx-mat-datepicker-actions>
        <button ngxMatDatepickerApply>
            <mat-icon>done</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </ngx-mat-datepicker-actions>
</ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
```

Comment: Worked for me, although there is a GitHub issue with it but working fine with Angular 15